# Assembler segmentation fault on dereference register address

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, dereference

I have a problem with x86 assembly (AT&T).

Because I need to implement an array lookup in assembler I have in the register %ebx the first item of the array (say arr[0]) and in order to point to arr[1] for example I wrote:

```
mov -4(%ebx), %eax
```

The problem is, I have a segmentation fault when I try to get the ebx's address, which is very strange because I can get the ebx's value (the value of arr[0]) without problems..
Some advices?

EDIT:
Ok, I think I understood the error.
When I declare the array I have to put on the variable arr the address of the first element:

```
mov -4(%ecx), %eax
```

But with this instruction i put the value not the address.
So how can I put the address?

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code? I think you're misunderstanding something about how registers work.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[1]` is actually rather *unlikely* to be at `-4[%ebx]`, it far more likely to be at `+4`.

But based on your question, I'm not sure you're understanding. That will only work if `%ebx` is the *address* of the first element in the array. Your text seems to indicate that you've loaded the *value* of `arr[0]` into `ebx` in which case, there's no way to get at the other elements from there.

You may need to post a little more code so that we can see what you're actually trying to do. Code generally trumps descriptive text for programming problems :-)